# gradle uploadArchives task to upload single flavor

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, nexus

i have an app with multiple product flavors. 
im using the maven plugin and the uploadArchives task to upload my apk to nexus, using this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle

my problem is running uploadArchives runs the build and assemble tasks for all flavors and uploads them to my nexus repo.

i want to be able to assemble and upload a single flavor and not necessarily all of them .

i dont understand exactly what uploadArchives does, why does it assemble the app ? shouldnt it only upload whatever was generated by an explicit assemble task?
how do i run it per flavor?

Thanks!

Comment: did you get it to work for a single flavor?

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem was to create another module that references the specific flavor and use uploadArchives on that module.

To add a dependency to a specific flavor use this line in your Gradle dependency section:

```
compile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'flavor')
```

Comment: How do you call uploadArchives on THAT module then ?

Comment: You place the uploadArchives function in the build.gradle file of the new module

Comment: That's what I have done but when I call :
./gradlew assemble
./gradlew -q uploadSnapshotArchives
I get an error : "Task 'uploadSnapshotArchives' not found in root project"

Comment: Ok, I was wrong with "uploadSnapshotArchives", I just use "uploadArchives" and then it works. Thanls for your answer +1

Answer (score 1):

The upload to the repository should upload all artifacts from the build, which in this case includes all flavours. This way you can guarantee that all artifacts in the repository are from the same codebase.

What is your use case to upload only some?

Comment: Running uploadArchives triggers the assemble task too so I can't control what's built, so if I want to assemble just one flavor and upload it I cant

Comment: well.. my question then is why would you only want to upload an incomplete set?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just build the productFlavor your interested in.  For example

`gradle clean assembleMyProductFlavor uploadArchives`  Then the upload should only see the flavor your interested as the other `apk` files don't exist.

Comment: not sure why but the uploadArchives task actually builds all flavors so and uploads all of them